# How to allow method DELETE in apache Laragon - laravel 10?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, http, laragon

I have a vanilla installation of `Laragon` and a vanilla installation of `Laravel` `v10` with `Jetstream`, i am using it as an `API` i have a separate project in `Vue` that consumes said `API`, all the login works.

I am using `axios` and it works when i am saving, i created a `model` and a `controller`, so i have a `NoteController` with the destroy function:

```
    public function destroy(Note $note)
    {
        
        $note->delete();

        return response()->noContent();
    }
```

when i do `php artisan route:list --name=note` i can see the delete route:

```
DELETE   api/note/{note}................. note.destroy › Api\NoteController@destroy
```

i am using in api.php :

```
Route::apiResource('/note', NoteController::Class);
```

In vue i am doing (where item is a note object):

```
api.delete<Note>('/api/note', { data: item })
```

i am getting a `405 Method Not Allowed`:

```
message
: 
"The DELETE method is not supported for route api/note. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST."
```

i can see in the response headers: 
[image]

I tried adding the following to `httpd.conf` inside the `<Directory "F:/laragon/www">` tag:

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
    Allow from all
</Limit>
```

and restarted Laragon, i still get the `405`.

I tried the other solutions from other questions in regards to Laravel config but i still have the error, and i see the route in `route:list`

Comment: because the path would be `api/note/{note-id}` not `api/note` ... you are not passing the id via the body of the request but as a route parameter

Comment: The message "The DELETE method is not supported for route..." is a Laravel message. So Laragon has already passed the request to Laravel. You problem is not with Laragon.

Comment: @lagbox yeah that was it, do you have any docs that explains why the route in `route:list` nor the destroy function suggests that? all was generated with artisan, the `destroy` function suggested a `Note` object as param and its not doing a `findByID` but a `$category->delete()`

Comment: it does say it ... right in the `rouet:list`; it is in your question ... `DELETE   api/note/{note}` ... that shows you need a route parameter `{note}` ...

Comment: @lagbox yes, but it also says that the function for it is `destroy` which is expecting an object (Note $note), which is used: `$note->delete()` thats where the confusion starts. It would be more clear to have `public function destroy(Note $id)` or similar

Comment: it is the `destroy` method ... and `Note $note` makes more sense since Implicit Model Binding is happening ... you are not expecting an ID to that method you are expecting the Object, the route definition expects the ID, not the method ([Implicit Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#implicit-binding))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call the API like this:

```js
api.delete<Note>(`/api/note/${item.id}`)
```

(Edit: Removed second parameter of api call: `{_method: 'delete'}`)

Comment: This worked without the `{_method: 'delete'}`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to pass _method=DELETE in JSON form request parameters.